# Invalid identifier in query y subquery

Tags: oracle

The following query returns the error:

```
ORA-00904: "C"."CHARGEDATE": invalid identifier 
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error en la línea: 6, columna: 58
```

The query is the following:

```
Select
    c.idChargeStation,
    c.idVehicleUnit,
    round(cc.totalTiempo/cc.totalCargas, 2) AS media,
    v.versionNameVU, 
    c.chargeDate, 
    p.firstName, 
    p.lastName
FROM 
    Charge c, 
    VehicleUnit v, 
    Person p,
    (
        SELECT 
            idChargeStation, 
            idVehicleUnit, 
            chargeDate, 
            SUM(totalPluggedTime) AS totalTiempo, 
            count(*) AS totalCargas
        FROM Charge  
        WHERE 
            idChargeStation =  c.idChargeStation 
            AND idVehicleUnit = c.idVehicleUnit
            AND chargeDate = c.chargeDate
    ) cc
WHERE
    c.idVehicleUnit = v.idVehicleUnit
    AND v.idClient = p.idPerson
    HAVING media > 600
    HAVING round(c.powerKwH/c.KmFromLast, 2) > 1.00
Order by c.chargeDate DESC;
```

There are 3 tables: `Charge`, `VehicleUnit`, `Person` :

- `idVehicleUnit` is a foreign key of `VehicleUnit` (`idVehicleUnit = idVehicleUnit`)
- `idClient` is foreign key of `Person` (`idClient = idPerson`)

I add information, composition the tables involved with the first 10 records of each table.

Table Charge:
[image: Table Charge]

Table VehicleUnit:
[image: Table VehicleUnit]

Table Person:
[image: Table Person]

The query must return the idChargeStation, idVehicleUnit, chargeDate fields of the charge table, the totalPluggedTime average, the versionNameVU field of the vehicleUnit table, and the firstName and lastName fields of the Person table.

the average is obtained by:
SUM (totalPluggedTime) AS totalTime
count (*) AS totalLoads <----- total subquery record where the requirements that the idChargeStation, idVehicleUnit and chargeDate are equal are met.
With that data in the main query round (cc.totalTime/ cc.totalLoads, 2) AS average

Comment: Not sure if you're asking in Spanish or Portuguese...but don't ask in either, use English please.  Regarding your question, your query makes no sense, because you have a subquery in the select clause which returns more than one column.  Showing us sample input and output data would really be helpful here.

Comment: In Greek, I'm speaking in Greek, what one has to read...

Answer (score 0):

Well I had some bad things in the query, but I have already solved it, also thank you very much, I put the correct query

```
    select c.idVehicleUnit, round(sum(c.totalPluggedTime)/count(*), 2) AS media, v.versionNameVU, p.firstName, p.lastName
    FROM charge c 
    inner join charge cc on c.idVehicleUnit = cc.idVehicleUnit  
    inner join vehicleUnit v on cc.idVehicleUnit = v.idVehicleUnit AND c.idVehicleUnit = cc.idVehicleUnit
    inner join person p on v.idClient = p.idPerson
    group by c.idVehicleUnit, v.versionNameVU, p.firstName, p.lastName, c.powerKwH, c.KmFromLast
    HAVING round(sum(c.totalPluggedTime)/count(*), 2) > (Select round(6*(sum(totalPluggedTime)/count(*)), 2) from charge)
    AND round(c.powerKwH/c.KmFromLast, 2) > 1.00 
    ORDER BY c.chargeDate DESC;
```